# Select records from NOW or LATER (not future timestamp)

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

How do I do this?

I have the table "news" and I want the page to show only news created from now are later
My idea is to pre-write news so article with timestamp 2011-12-18 12:00 will automatically appear on sunday noon

shouldn´t it be like

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE timestamp is NOW() or LATER ORDER BY timestamp");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're wanting `news` where the timestamp is anytime prior to the current time? So the news on 2011-12-18 wouldn't show until it was noon on that day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE timestamp <= NOW() ORDER BY timestamp");
```

try that...

Keep in mind - your post suggests you're not using a timestamp. You appear to be using a  datetime datatype. My answer would work for datetime.

Also, I think your title is misleading. By your question it looks like you're making a queue so things will be posted by the date you provide. If in the future, then it does not display the article until that date.

Comment: Thanx it works perfectly. Well, yes... I´m running a news page and I usually write 8-10 articles each day... tomorrow I´ll be away and going to a party in the evening so question is: How will be writing new articles? .... so with this script I´ll just start writing and I choose the date and time when they appear while I´m away